# Byte Pattern Finding (Needle in Haystack) - Wildcard/Mask?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, wildcard, mask

this is my first time using StackOverflow so sorry if I'm vague :P

I have this piece of code, which searches for a pattern in a byte array and returns it's position.

```
public int FindPattern(byte[] Body, byte[] Pattern, int start = 0)
    {
        int foundIndex = -1;
        bool match = false;

        if (Body.Length > 0 && Pattern.Length > 0 && start <= Body.Length - Pattern.Length && Pattern.Length <= Body.Length)
            for (int index = start; index <= Body.Length - Pattern.Length; index += 4)
                if (Body[index] == Pattern[0])
                {
                    match = true;
                    for (int index2 = 1; index2 <= Pattern.Length - 1; index2++)
                    {
                        if (Body[index + index2] != Pattern[index2])
                        {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    if (match)
                    {
                        foundIndex = index;
                        break;
                    }
                }

        return foundIndex;
    }
```

The Problem is I don't know how I would go about in including Byte Masking/Wildcards.

For Example, if I wanted to find the following byte pattern:

```
0x5A, 0xC7, 0xAE, 0xB7, 0x2F
```

How would I implement wildcard searching so if I don't know some bytes in the byte array or they change, for example, how would I find a pattern like the following:

```
0x5A, 0x??, 0xAE, 0xB7, 0x??
```

?? = Represents Bytes that I don't know which changes, from time to time.

Does anyone have a solution? - I have looked around but can't find much info

Many Thanks In Advance!,
James

Comment: Your current method signature provides no way to get the wildcard matching.  You need to start by either add another argument to help you mark which patterns are wildcards, or change your byte pattern to a data type that can carry a bit more information (like a custom object or string).

Comment: Thanks :) If I converted to a string, how would I return the position though?

Comment: Well if you turned `pattern` into a string like those in your example (with the `0x??`) you could cast pieces of the string back into byte[] and use the other pieces in your logic to skip some indices (skip 8 bits since the whole byte is wildcard)?  It's still a little bit strange, since you would have to encode the string wherever you call this method.

Comment: Convert to hex string...apply regex and back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your code to support wildcards is easy enough. Making it efficient for searching in large bodies of data will probably require a more sophisticated algorithm, like Boyer-Moore with wildcards (sorry, I don't have the code lying around).

Here's one way of doing the former (off the top of my head):

```
public int FindPattern(byte[] Body, byte[] Pattern, bool[] Wild, int start = 0)
    {
        int foundIndex = -1;
        bool match = false;

        if (Body.Length > 0 
            && Pattern.Length > 0 
            && start <= Body.Length - Pattern.Length && Pattern.Length <= Body.Length)
            for (int index = start; index <= Body.Length - Pattern.Length; index += 4)

                if (Wild[0] || (Body[index] == Pattern[0]))
                {
                    match = true;
                    for (int index2 = 1; index2 <= Pattern.Length - 1; index2++)
                    {
                        if (!Wild[index2] &&
                          (Body[index + index2] != Pattern[index2]))
                        {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    if (match)
                    {
                        foundIndex = index;
                        break;
                    }
                }

        return foundIndex;
    }
```

The expectation here is that you pass in the search pattern in its full length and then a wildcard flag array with the same length, so your example

```
0x5A, 0x??, 0xAE, 0xB7, 0x??
```

would be passed in as

```
0x5A, 0x00, 0xAE, 0xB7, 0x00, and then
false, true, false, false, true
```